# Offline page in service worker does not work

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I am creating an offline version of my website. I have a service worker file that contains all the logic. When there is an internet connection, the files are stored in the cache. However, when there is no internet connection, the files are not taken from the cache, and the offline page does not work.

The strategy of my service worker file should be as follows: When a user enters the application, a request is made to the network, and all the data is cached. There are also pre-cached data. When there is no internet connection, the user is shown the previously cached page or the page they were navigating to. If that page is not in the cache, the user should be shown the offline page.

The code of my service worker that doesn't work.

**sw.js**

```
const cacheCordova = "c-app-v3";

const assetsUrls = [
"/local/templates/mobilePwaMyClub/css/mobileStyle.css",
"/mobile-myclub/offline.php",
];

self.addEventListener("install", function (event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheCordova).then(function (cache) {
      return cache.addAll(assetsUrls);
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
  if (event.data && event.data.action === "logout") {
    event.waitUntil(
      caches.keys().then(function (cacheNames) {
        return Promise.all(
          cacheNames
            .filter(function (cacheName) {
              return cacheName !== cacheCordova;
            })
            .map(function (cacheName) {
              console.log("true");
              return caches.delete(cacheName);
            })
        );
      })
    );
  }
});

self.addEventListener("activate", async (event) => {
  const cacheNames = await caches.keys();
  await Promise.all(
    cacheNames
      .filter((name) => name !== cacheCordova)
      .map((name) => caches.delete(name))
  );
});

self.addEventListener("fetch", function (event) {
  if (navigator.onLine) {
    console.log("network");

    event.respondWith(
      fetch(event.request).then(function (networkResponse) {
        if (
          !networkResponse ||
          networkResponse.status !== 200 ||
          networkResponse.type !== "basic" ||
          event.request.method === "POST"
        ) {
          return networkResponse;
        }
        var responseToCache = networkResponse.clone();
        caches.open(cacheCordova).then(function (cache) {
          cache.put(event.request, responseToCache);
        });
        return networkResponse;
      })
    );
  } else {
    console.log("NOT network");

    event
      .respondWith(
        caches.open(cacheCordova).then(function (cache) {
          cache.match(event.request).then(function (cacheResponse) {
            return cacheResponse;
          });
        })
      )
      .catch(function () {
        return caches.match("/mobile-myclub/offline.php");
      });
  }
});
```

I was able to implement functionality that caches all data and the pages visited by the user. If the user doesn't have an internet connection, the cached page they previously visited is displayed. If the requested page is not in the cache, an offline page is shown. However, the problem is that the data needs to be constantly updated, and caching should only work when there is no internet connection. There are also issues with user authorization. If a new user accesses the application from the same device, they see the old cached version of a different user.

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", function (event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches
      .match(event.request)
      .then(function (response) {
        if (response) {
          return response;
        }
        return fetch(event.request).then(function (response) {
          if (
            !response ||
            response.status !== 200 ||
            response.type !== "basic" ||
            event.request.method === "POST"
          ) {
            return response;
          }

          var responseToCache = response.clone();
          caches.open(cacheCordova).then(function (cache) {
            cache.put(event.request, responseToCache);
          });

          return response;
        });
      })
      .catch(function () {
        return caches.match("/mobile-myclub/offline.php");
      })
  );
});
```

Please help me solve the problem.